# Repair the EFI Bootloader in Windows 8 diskpart not working

Tags: windows-8, boot

I have an HP ENVY 14-k074ca with win 8 on it. Two days ago it did update to win 8.1. After that it crashed and went into the infinite loop of automatic recovery. I THEN tried to use a win8 USB to solve the problem. of course auto recovery not working.

Refresh your system display : "the drive where windows is installed is locked. Unlock the drive and try again"

Also restore to factory setting found no image. When run diagnostic i got the error : 0xc0000098 error on boot/bcd

I used the command line tried :

```
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /rebuildmbr
```

success but nothing happened it detect 0 installed window.

and here is the thing when i try

chkdisk

found bad on on-disk uppercase table

chkdsk /f

the type of file system is NTFS can not lock current drive

also

sfc /scannow display

windows resource protection could not start th repaire service

the last propose was diskpart but when I run it display the tool version but diskpart> prompet never appear.

can someone help me i really need the data on my PC and the programs installed on it.

Comment: The SFC you attempted was trying to scan the windows recovery environment you were booted to.  You have to provide the Windows installation and do an offline scan instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance you're facing an HDD failure, but you can try to run the following commands from your Windows 8 USB media:

```
bootsect /nt60 ALL /force
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

Then restart.

If it doesn't solve your boot problem I strongly advise you to boot on some Windows PE based CD/USB media with a GUI ([Hiren's boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/) for example) and connect an external HDD to try backuping your important files.